# Is there any hard drive imaging software for Windows that is free or open source?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-image

I've used O&O DiskImage 3 and was not very impressed with it. Are there any good alternatives that are free or open source?

Comment: Perhaps also have someone add information on how to actually USE these versions? It's nice to make an image, but if you don't know how to restore it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). It is free and from what I've heard works good too!

Comment: I agree, though it doesn't work on Windows 2000 (which was a problem for me but shouldn't affect many people these days)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/backupandimage.shtml) for a list of free software.

Answer (score 1):

I think clonezilla is an open source version of imaging software.  I know people who say that it worked very well for them.

http://clonezilla.org/ is where this little wonder can be found.  Hope this helps!